# How to get the exception that failed a Kotlin coroutine job?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

[kotlinx.coroutines.Job](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html)

> A coroutine job is said to complete exceptionally when its body throws an exception

However, I'm not seeing anything in the API that returns the exception that failed the job. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: If you join the job (suspending joining) then if job fails, the exception will be re-thrown to the waiting coroutine, so you can have a traditional try catch block to handle that.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu That is true, but you may still pass a `Job` reference around without joining it.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Actually the description of job says "This invocation resumes normally (without exception) when the job is complete for any reason". So would it really rethrow?

Comment: Here is the Kdoc [link to join](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/join.html) where @findusl quoted from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP here, figured it out.

```
job.getCancellationException().cause
```

is what I was looking for.